# Create own login page with flask using HTTPBasicAuth

Tags: python, authentication, flask, basic-authentication

I followed [this tutorial](https://flask-httpauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to create a basic authentication system using Flask. Now I want to create my own login page. When I run the tutorial code, an automatic login window opens. But I don't want that. I want a seperate login page to open. If you try to enter the private page without logging in, you should be redirected to the login page.

Here is the code where I tried to connect "login_required" to the login page with "verify_password".

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth

app = Flask(__name__)
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@auth.verify_password
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if(request.form['username'] and request.form['password'] == "123"):
                return "<h1>Private page</h1>"

        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('login.html')


@app.route('/private', methods=['GET'])
@auth.login_required
def private():
    return "<h1>Private page</h1>"

@app.route('/public', methods=['GET'])
def public():
    return "<h1>Public page</h1>"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to create a login form.

The plugin you mentioned is built to make use of basic auth, as the name suggests. This will always trigger the browser popup you described.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it would be possible to just use the framework from flask_httpauth. I´ll check Flask-Login out.